# Why can't I execute my xlabel offset on my gnuplot bash script?

Tags: bash, gnuplot

I have been following various tutorials on how to run gnuplot and I have come up with this script. So far it is going well enough but when I try to change the offset on the `xlabel` or `ylabel` I get a message saying this in the terminal:

```
gnuplot> set xlabel "Applied Current [mA]" -0.3 
                                           ^
         line 0: ';' expected
```

I was wracking my brain so I even tested example xlabel and ylabel off the internet and the same type of error came up

```
#!/bin/bash

gnuplot << TOEND
# Set the output file
set terminal postscript eps color enhanced 
set output 'fp.eps' 
unset key

set title "Voltage as a Function of Current" 

set noborder 
set xtics axis
set ytics axis

set format x "%2.0f" 
set format y "%2.0f" 

u(x)=m*x+b
fit u(x) "nfp.dat" using 1:2 via m,b

v(x)=m*x+b
fit v(x) "wfp.dat" using 1:2 via m,b

set xzeroaxis linestyle 2 lt 1 lc 0
set xlabel "Applied Current [mA]" -0.3 

set yzeroaxis linestyle  2 lt 1 lc 0
set ylabel "Voltage [mV]" 


set xrange [ -15.00 : 15.00 ]
set yrange [ -20.0 : 20.0 ]

plot  'nfp.dat' using 1:2, \
       v(x), 'wfp.dat' using 1:2, \
      'sfp.dat' using 1:2 


TOEND
convert -density 100 fp.eps fp.png
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are missing the `offset` flag.  Try:

```
set xlabel "Applied Current [mA]" offset -0.3
```